# Can I use Biicode to install GCC 4.9 and Clang 3.5 on Travis?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, travis-ci, biicode

Currently, the following except from my `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
  - wget http://apt.biicode.com/install.sh && chmod +x install.sh && ./install.sh
  - bii setup:cpp
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ bii setup:cpp
WARN: This setup is EXPERIMENTAL.
Please refer to the docs for manual installation if something fails
cmake version 2.8.7
Invalid cmake version 2.8.7 < 3.0 in your path
WARN: You are running in non-interactive mode.
A CMake local copy will be installed automatically.
Please run with '-i' or '--interactive' for more options
Downloading and installing CMake 3.0.2
Download  cmake-3.0.2-Linux-64.tar.gz
from  https://s3.amazonaws.com/biibinaries/thirdparty/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-64.tar.gz
download to  /tmp/tmpuO7mZ_/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-64.tar.gz
Percent: [########################################] 100.0% of 10.1Mb Done...
INFO: Extracting cmake
cmake version 3.0.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
Valid cmake version 3.0.2 > 3.0 in "/home/travis/.biicode/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-64/bin"
CMake 3.0.2 installed ok
gcc 4.6.3 already installed
g++ 4.6.3 already installed
```

I've check for options to the `bii setup:cpp` command but can't seem to find anything about this, am I missing something or do I have to install them externally to bii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nop. The command `bii setup:cpp` is very basic, just for C++ newbies and for a quick basic setup of mainstream gcc based compilers. You can see the source code: https://github.com/biicode/client/blob/develop/setups/installers/gnu_compiler_installer.py#L9

- In Win it will install MinGW 4.8
- In Ubuntu it will install the distribution build-essential, which for latest Ubuntu should be gcc 4.8.2
- In Mac it will install the standard XCode, with the mainstream CLang distribution.

If you want to install in travis-ci those compilers, it can be sometimes quite tricky. I suggest using the scripts in https://github.com/biicode/misc. You can probably directly wget them and execute from your travis build.

Comment: thanks for the scripts. they look like the way to go!